# What's the best way to split an array into multiple arrays every time an element is met?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm fairly new to JS and still learning. I have this array:

```
[A,true,B,true,C,true,D,true,E,A,true,B,true,C,false,E,A,true,B,false,E]
```

What's the best way to split said array into multiple arrays everytime E occurs?

ie. the above array becomes:

```
[A,true,B,true,C,true,D,true,E]
[A,true,B,true,C,false,E]
[A,true,B,false,E]
```

**What I have tried:**

I have tried converting the array into a string and splitting it, yet the result isn't satisfactory.

```
var pathsString = paths.toString();
pathsString = pathsString.split("," + end).filter(function(el) {return el.length != 0});
//end is E in this case
```

Thank you

Comment: Ruby has a neat method called [`Enumerable#slice_when`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when) that does what you ask, but it does not exist in JavaScript, and LoDash doesn't supply it either. Looks like you'll have to code it yourself.

Comment: Looks like you've received some good answers below. I upvoted the best solutions (using `Array.reduce()`). You could take one of those and use it to implement `Array.slice_when()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const arr = ['A',true,'B',true,'C',true,'D',true,'E','A',true,'B',true,'C',false,'E','A',true,'B',false,'E'];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, x) => {
  acc[acc.length-1].push(x)
  if (x === 'E') acc.push([]);
  return acc;
}, [[]]).filter(x => x.length);

console.log(result);
```

Here are some explanations:

- `Array.reduce()` iterates over the an array and passes an accumulator from one iteration to the next. This accumulator (`acc`) is initialized to `[[]]` at the beginning (an array with an empty group).
- At each iteration, we take the last group in `acc` and append the value `x` to that group.
- If the value equals `E`, we also push a new empty group for the next iteration.
- Then, we filter out the empty groups left out if `E` was the last letter or if the input array was empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can chunk the array with `Array.reduce()`:

```js
const arr = ['A',true,'B',true,'C',true,'D',true,'E','A',true,'B',true,'C',false,'E','A',true,'B',false,'E']

const result = arr.reduce((r, c, i) => {
  if(!i || c === 'E') r.push([]) // if it's the 1st item, or the item is E push a new sub array
  
  r[r.length - 1].push(c) // push the item to the last sub array
  
  return r
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var original = ['A',true,'B',true,'C',true,'D',true,'E','A',true,'B',true,'C',false,'E','A',true,'B',false,'E'];
// make a copy of the original, just so we are not changing it
var temp = original.slice(0);
// the variable we will collect all the sub arrays in
var result = [];

// while the temp still has data to evaluate, loop
while (temp.length) {
  // find the next position of the first character in the temp array
  // add one since the index was affected by us slicing off the first character
  var lastIndex = temp.slice(1).indexOf(temp[0]) + 1;
  
  // if the lastIndex is not 0, add the sub array
  if (lastIndex) {
    // push the sub array
    result.push(temp.slice(0, lastIndex));
    // remove the sub array from temp so its not processed again
    temp = temp.slice(lastIndex);
  } else {
    // index was zero, so the indexOf was -1 (not found), so it's the last subarray
    result.push(temp);
    // set to empty list so the loop ends
    temp = [];
  }
}

console.log(result);
```